# How to reverse my input including the negative

Tags: c++, loops, int, reverse

This is my code that I have currently but it always outputs 0 I'm trying to get it to output the reverse of the input including the negative for example -123425 will be 524321-:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int number;
    bool negative;
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    cin >> number;
    while (number != 0) {
        number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    if (number < 0) {
        negative = true;
        number = -number;
        cout << number << "-";
    }
    else {
        negative = false;
    }
    cout << number << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `number % 10;` does?

Comment: Read your number as a string.  Reverse the string (in place).  There are standard methods for reversing.  You may have to add a special case for the `'-'` character.  Don't bother with `number % 10` stuff, not necessary since you are dealing with digits.  They are much easier manipulated as characters.

Comment: Presumably this is for an assignment. If there's no restrictions, then as Thomas said, use strings. If you must use numbers, then you would use a recursive function.

Comment: @ChrisMM my professor wanted me to use the % and stuff or atleast that what he made it seem. He definitely wanted us to use a while loop where it it takes the last integer of the number puts it in the output and keeps doing it until the number = 0

Comment: number % 10 computes the remainder of number divided by 10. But you do not do anything with it. You might want to assign (with the = operator) the result of this operation to another variable, and continue your computation. The same apply to number /= 10. You might want to display number during the while loop as well to better understand what is happening at each iteration => cout << number << "\n";

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the input to a `std::string`, then reverse its content with [`std::reverse`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

```
#include <algorithm> // reverse
#include <cstdlib>   // EXIT_SUCCESS
#include <iostream>  // cin, cout, endl
#include <string>    // string, to_string

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter an integer: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    auto str = to_string(number);

    reverse(str.begin(), str.end());
    cout << str << endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Reading to an `int` first - and not to a `std::string` - makes sure that we parse a valid integer from the input. Converting it to a `std::string` allow us to reverse it. This let us feed inputs like `-042` and `-0` to the program, and get `24-` and `0` as a result, not `240-` and `0-`.

Comment: Please stop updating my answer.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow I believe your answer is the correct solution to the question. I edited it because I thought there's a minor mistake - as insignificant as it is - that might confuse some people. In my first edit I wanted to improve one other thing, that I realize now introduced an error. In my later update I strictly corrected the one that I still think is a mistake. I'm not planning to submit any more changes, but it would help me if you point out what I did wrong in the *latest* one.

Answer (score 1):

After the first loop

```
while (number != 0) {
    number % 10;
    number /= 10;
}
```

the variable `number` is equal to `0`.

So the following if statement

```
if (number < 0) {
    negative = true;
    number = -number;
    cout << number << "-";
}
else {
    negative = false;
}
```

does not make sense.

Pay attention to that it can happen such a way that a reversed number can not fit in an object of the type int. So for the result number you should select a larger integer type.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the assignment can be done.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
    std::cout << "Enter an integer: ";

    int n = 0;

    std::cin >> n;

    bool negative = n < 0;
    const int Base = 10;

    long long int result = 0;

    do
    {
        int digit = n % Base;
        if ( digit < 0 ) digit = -digit;
        result = Base * result + digit;  
    } while ( n /= Base );

    std::cout << result;
    if ( negative ) std::cout << '-';
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look like

```
Enter an integer: 123456789
987654321-
```

Comment: I would have guard against possible UB and initialize  `n`. Not all implementations guaranteed to initialize `n` in case of invalid input even if standard *now* requires it. Otherwise it's perfect

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use String or have to use int, here is the solution.

You want to check the negativity before you make changes to the number, otherwise the number would be 0 when it exit the while loop. Also, the modulus would be negative if your number is negative.

number % 10 only takes the modulus of the number, so you want to cout this instead of just leaving it there.

The last line you have `cout << number << endl;` will cout 0 since number has to be 0 to exit the while loop.

```
    if(number < 0) {
      number = -number;
      negative = true;
    }
    while (number != 0) {
        cout << number % 10;
        number /= 10;
    }
    if (negative) {
        cout << "-"<< endl;
    }
```

EDIT: With a broader assumption of the input taking all int type values instead of the reversed integer being a valid int type. Here is a modified solution.

```
    if(number < 0) {
      negative = true;
    }
    while (number != 0) {
        cout << abs(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
    if (negative) {
        cout << "-"<< endl;
    }
```

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Put the OP's code in a compiler and replace the while loop, if - else statement and the last line with my code, then claim my proposal to be incorrect, thank you.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Since the OP is storing the reversed number in an int and outputting it, I am assuming that it is guaranteed to not overflow.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If you are really picky about the input of int_min, then just declare number as long and the whole overflowing issue is solved.

Comment: And the same problem will exist.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow It won't. I am not storing the resulting number anywhere.

Comment: You are mistaken. Here you are number = -number;.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow number is declared as long as my previous comment suggests

Comment: This changes nothing.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow declaring number as long would get rid of the issue with number = -number when int_min is inputed

Comment: In this case the user can enter the  LONG_MIN value. And moreover in some systems the type long can have the same range as the type int.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow The OP is only considering int input, LONG_MIN is not a valid input under the original intention. In those systems, you would use long long instead.

Comment: You are mistaken. He considers input corresponding to his declaration of the variable number. If he will declare it as long then he will consider integers of the type long.

Comment: Since he was only declaring int in the first place, he only needs to consider int type inputs. Therefore, if the declaration is changed to type long, he still only needs to consider int type inputs.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow If you don't want to take the absolute value, then just get rid of this line and take the absolute value of the modulus before you cout. This way not even long is needed and he can stick to type int.

Comment: Why are you talking all this me?! The code should be correct without your speech. Or are you an application to the code?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Why are you adding extra conditions?! My code is correct with the original conditions from the OP where the reversed int can be stored in an int. This is what he is doing in the first place.

Comment: I added nothing to your code. I only pointed to that your code is bad and nothing more. The problem is that you do not understand this.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple:

```
int reverse(int n){
    int k = abs(n);     //removes the negative signal
    while(k > 0){
        cout<<k % 10;   //prints the last character of the number
        k /= 10;        //cuts off the last character of the number
    }
    if(n < 0) cout<<"-";    //prints the - in the end if the number is initially negative
    cout<<endl;
}

int main(){
    int n = -1030;     //number you want to reverse
    reverse(n);
}
```

Comment: Can you prove it?

Comment: For example try to apply the function abs for an integer equal to INT_MIN.

Comment: This is true, since `INT_MIN` is `-2147483648`, if you take the absolute of this, it would be `2147483648` that exceeds the limit of an integer. For any other case, the code will work just fine. One just need to add a condition for this case, use long or do another solution with strings.

Answer (score 0):

I think trying to visualize the process of your program is a great way to see if your solution is doing what you expect it to. To this end, let's assume that our `number` is going to be `12345`. The code says that while this is not equal to `0`, we will do `number % 10` and then `number /= 10`. So if we have `12345`, then:

`number % 10` --> `12345 % 10` --> `5` is not assigned to any value, so no change is made. This will be true during each iteration of the while loop, except for different values of `number` along the way.

`number /= 10` --> `12345 /= 10` --> `1234`

`number /= 10` --> `1234 /= 10` --> `123`

`number /= 10` --> `123 /= 10` --> `12`

`number /= 10` --> `12 /= 10` --> `1`

`number /= 10` --> `1 /= 10` --> `0` (because of integer division)

Now that `number == 0` is true, we proceed to the `if/else` block, and since `number < 0` is false we will always proceed to the `else` block and then finish with the `cout` statement. Note that the while loop will **require** `number == 0` be true to exit, so this program will always output `0`.

To work around this, you will likely either need to create a separate number where you can store the final digits as you loop through, giving them the correct weight by multiplying them by powers of 10 (similar to what you are hoping to do), or cast your number to a string and print each index of the string in reverse using a loop.

Answer (score -1):

using namespace std;

int main()

{

```
int number,flag=1;
long long int revnum=0;
bool negative;
cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> number;
if(number<0)
{   negative=true;

}
while (number > 0) {
    revnum=revnum*10+number %10;   
    number /= 10;
}
if (negative)
{     revnum=(-revnum);
     cout << revnum << '-'<<endl;
 }
 else
 { cout<<revnum<<endl;
  }


return 0;
```

}

A few changes I did -

1. checking the number whether it's negative or positive
2. if negative converting it to positive

3.reversing the number with the help of a new variable revnum

4.and the printing it according to the requirement

To reverse the num-

revnum=revnum*10 + number%10

then num=num/10

like let's try to visualize

1.take a number for example like 342

2.for 1st step revnum=0 so revnum*10=0 and num%10=2 , so revnum will be 2

3. and the number now is num/10 so 34

4.next now rev = 2 the rev*10=20 and num%10=4 then rev*10 + num/10 =24

5.finally we get 243

Hope it helps :)

edit:-
just a small edit to solve the problem of the overflow of int , made revnum as long long int.

Comment: Your code is invalid because for example INT_MIN can not be represented in 2's complement system as a positive number of the type int.

Comment: In general when you post an answer like this you should explain what OP did wrong or just add comments instead of just giving them a solution